# if i have admin rights on a machine why can't i uninstall this software

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall

i am trying to uninstall a number of pieces of software on my machine.  I have admin rights but a number of items are rejecting this uninstall process due to privilege.  Here is an example:

[image]

any idea why i can't uninstall this or does everyone have any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you are an administrator does not mean you **currently** have rights to that directory/file. Give yourself rights to the folder/file using the Security Properties dialog box. (Right click on the folder/file, click the security tab, and edit permissions there)